# How to show t stat and p value with coefficient with stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I would like to display the t value and p value from my regression output using the stargazer package. So far, I've found ways to show one or the other. I did find [something](https://rdrr.io/github/johnhenrypezzuto/blpl/man/stargazer_pvalues.html) online that displays both; however, it omits the coefficient names. Is there a function or something else that will enable me to show all three?

```
library(stargazer)
data("cars")
model <- lm(hp ~ wt, mtcars)
stargazer(model, type='text',report = "csp")
```

**Shows p-values, but no beta coefficient names**
[image: table output]

**shows beta coefficient names, but no pvalues. I would like to keep all three: coefficient names, t stat, and p-value**

[image: output not including p-value]

**edit**

removed a function used on the website that I did not use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mention it by using t in the `report` argument:

> a character string containing only elements of "v", "c", "s","t", "p",
> "*" that determines whether, and in which order, variable names ("v"),
> coefficients ("c"), standard errors/confidence intervals ("s"), test
> statistics ("t") and p-values ("p") should be reported in regression
> tables. If one of the aforementioned letters is followed by an
> asterisk ("*"), significance stars will be reported next to the
> corresponding statistic.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(stargazer)
data("cars")
model <- lm(hp ~ wt, mtcars)
stargazer(model, type='text', report = "vcstp")
#> 
#> ===============================================
#>                         Dependent variable:    
#>                     ---------------------------
#>                                 hp             
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> wt                            46.160           
#>                               (9.625)          
#>                              t = 4.796         
#>                             p = 0.00005        
#>                                                
#> Constant                      -1.821           
#>                              (32.325)          
#>                             t = -0.056         
#>                              p = 0.956         
#>                                                
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> Observations                    32             
#> R2                             0.434           
#> Adjusted R2                    0.415           
#> Residual Std. Error      52.437 (df = 30)      
#> F Statistic           22.999*** (df = 1; 30)   
#> ===============================================
#> Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi! I would like it to keep the beta estimates for wt and the constant. I'll post a photo of what it should look like but with p-values. EDIT: And the names of the independent variables

Comment: @bandcar, Please check updated code! You should include v in the report argument for variable names.

Comment: Hi @Quinten! Is it possible to have p-values in the parentheses instead of being denoted as "p = ...." without having to change them manually? I want to show only the coefficient, significance stars and p values in parentheses. Thanks

Comment: Hi @fsure, Unfortunately, I can’t help you right now. I am able to help you in a couple of days. Otherwise you could ask this as a new question? Thanks